# Hide element if element not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i hide a element when a spefific code is not found?

**EXAMPLE:**

If this code does not exist:

```
<div id="tab-1"></div>
```

This element should be hidden:

```
<li>
   <a id="tab-data" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
<li>
```

I think the only solution would be a script

Comment: What do you mean if that string does not exist? That is an element....

Comment: Sorry, i think that was the wrong word. I mean a HTML code

Comment: so  all element which don't have `Tab 1` need to be hide?

Comment: divs do not have href's either....

Comment: Sorry i meant <a>. Yes Alive-to-Die

Comment: if ($("#tab-1").length > 0){ 
  ///do something
}

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure but i think it will help you, it will hide which div no content

```js
$('ul li').each(function () {
        if((typeof $('a',  this).attr('href')) === 'undefined') {
        $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="tab-data1" href="#tab-3">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="tab-data2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="tab-data3" href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But i want to hide the tabs not the tab content. I already have a script that hides the tabs if the referred tab has no content in it. The problem is when there is no code the tab apperes anyway. So i need the script that hides the tab if the tab content could not be found.

Comment: @papito-air-max can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

This function could help you

```
function hideElementIfStringNotFound(jqElement, stringToFind){
    var text = jqElement.text();
    if(text.indexOf(stringToFind) >= 0){
        jqElement.show();
    } else {
        jqElement.hide();
    }
}
```

Whit that :

```
hideElementIfStringNotFound($("#tab-data"),"test");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if($('li div').text()=='')
  {
    $(this).hide();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
   <div id="tab-data" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</div>
</li>
<li>
   <div id="tab-data" href="#tab-2"></div>
</li>
<li>
   <div id="tab-data" href="#tab-3">Tab 2</div>
</li>
<li>
   <div id="tab-data" href="#tab-4">Tab 3</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

did you mean like this?

Comment: No not really, i want to hide a other element

Answer (score 0):

First check if the element length in the document is greater than 0

Here's how you do it:

```
var selector = $( '#tab-data' ).parent();
if ( selector.length < 1 ) {
    selector.hide();
}
```

The .parent() method will transverse one level upward in the document, getting the parent of the  element.

Better still, to hide just the anchor element , remove the .parent() method.

```
var selector = $( '#tab-data' );
if ( selector.length < 1 ) {
    selector.hide();
}
```

Comment: But i want to hide <li>
   <a id="tab-data" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
<li> not the #tab-1